# Failed to write core dump , A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

I got an error when i used fasttext to get a vector for a word using Jfasttext library in java . the error is

```
     A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f412c606444, pid=14379, tid=139916342187776
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_121) (build 1.7.0_121-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.121-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.8
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.3
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjniFastTextWrapper.so+0x1e444]  
FastTextWrapper::FastTextApi::getVector(std::string const&)+0x24
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because you haven't load the model yet.

You can find out how to load the trained model [here](https://github.com/vinhkhuc/JFastText/blob/dbff91988fab913392233a26bc1cf4ee14064923/src/test/java/com/github/jfasttext/JFastTextTest.java#L83). There you can also take a look at how  to [train supervised models](https://github.com/vinhkhuc/JFastText/blob/dbff91988fab913392233a26bc1cf4ee14064923/src/test/java/com/github/jfasttext/JFastTextTest.java#L13) or [unsupervised models](https://github.com/vinhkhuc/JFastText/blob/dbff91988fab913392233a26bc1cf4ee14064923/src/test/java/com/github/jfasttext/JFastTextTest.java#L24).

The function `loadModel()` works with all of these models.